# Android Studio UI becomes too small

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My PC is running Windows 10. After I put my laptop to sleep, and open Android Studio, the IDE UI becomes too small. 
It reaches a point that it's even smaller than my cursor, and I cannot see the text clearly. how can I fix this?
[Here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GU2p.png)

Comment: Hello Ramma, I suggest you provide a little bit more information. Like, for instance, what operating system you're using... which is quite important. That being said, I've never seen this issue on macOS or Linux. It seems you may be using Windows, (I infer that thanks to the D:/ path seen at the top) but it's just a guess.

Comment: yeah, im using windows 10, im forgot to tell about my OS.

Comment: Have you tried closing it and opening it again?

Comment: i've try to close and reopening it again, but everytime i reopen the ui become more smaller than before, i dont know how to solve this